# Adding a Less Than filter to a pivot table in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I'm trying to add a filter to a column in a pivot table whenever a worksheet is activated in Excel.

I have the following so far:

```
   Dim pvt As PivotTable
   Dim pvtField As PivotField

   Set pvt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("MyPivotTable")
   Set pvtField = pvt.PivotFields("MyPivotColumnTopField")

   'First refresh the table
   pvt.RefreshTable

   'Clear Out Any Previous Filtering
   pvtField.ClearAllFilters

   'Add the less than filter
   pvtField.PivotFilters.Add xlValueIsLessThan, Value1:="1000"
```

But I get an `Invalid Procedure call or argument` error on the line that is trying to add the filter.

I've also tried:

```
   pvtField.PivotFilters.Add(xlValueIsLessThan, Value1:="1000")
```

but get a syntax error with that.

I'm looking at the documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pivotfilters-add-method-excel but cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @jeffreyweir's answer (which did a string based filter for me), here is a working example of using `.Add2` with both a string based filter and a numerical filter.

This is my example table and pivot table:
[image: Example Excel Table]

And this is code I have behind each button:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim pf As PivotField

    Set pf = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Numbers")
    pf.ClearAllFilters
    pf.PivotFilters.Add2 Type:=xlCaptionIsLessThan, Value1:="11"
End Sub

Sub Button2_Click()
Dim pf As PivotField

    Set pf = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Numbers")
    pf.ClearAllFilters
    pf.PivotFilters.Add2 Type:=xlCaptionIsLessThan, Value1:=11

End Sub

Sub Button3_Click()
Dim pf As PivotField

    Set pf = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Numbers")
    pf.ClearAllFilters
End Sub
```

Note that:

- `Button1` is the `Show < "11"` button which does a string based filter
- `Button2` is the `Show < 11` button which does a numeric filter
- `Button3` is the `Show All` button which removes the filter

When I click the `Show < "11"` button (i.e. Button1) I get the following result:

[image: After clicking Button1]

When I click the `Show < 11` button (i.e. Button2) I get the following (desired) result:

[image: After clicking Button3]

Answer (score 0):

You're using .Add but you should be using .Add2 as per that link.

```
pf.PivotFilters.Add2 Type:=xlCaptionIsLessThan, Value1:=1000
```

(I note that link has the correct syntax at the top, but the incorrect syntax at the bottom).

Normally the easiest way to troubleshoot syntax like this is to fire up the Macro recorder, perform your actions manually, then inspect the code. In this case, that's problematic. For instance, if I start with the PivotTable shown below right:

[image]

...and then clear all filters before setting a Label filter:

[image]
[image]

...then I get the exact result I want:

[image]

...and I get the following code:

```
Sub Macro6()

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Test").ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Test").PivotFilters.Add2 _
        Type:=xlCaptionIsLessThan, Value1:="11"
End Sub
```

But weirdly when I run that code, I get this:

[image]

Despite the fact that the Macro Recorder spits out code with the 11 in a string i.e. "11", you *don't* want to feed in a string. Why the Macro Recorder would tell you otherwise is beyond me.

Comment: Almost perfect... That does a string based filter - using `Value1:=1000` (i.e. without the quotes) works perfectly. If you could add the numerical less than version to your answer as well I'll gladly accept. (I did actually try `.Add2` but thought I was getting exactly the same errors - I must have had other syntax problems when I was trying it - I was getting very confused)

Comment: Is this for a Values filter? i.e. you want to filter the aggregated values in the Values area of the PivotTable from the perspective of MyPivotColumnTopField? See my edited answer above to see what my question relates to.

Comment: I'm actually just using PivotTables to extract data from a bigger data set so the pivot table is displaying everything in tabular form without any totals or other calculations. Some of the view only require a further subset of that extracted data, though, hence the numeric filter requirement.

Comment: The code works fine for me as is. See my revised answer.

Comment: I'll post a new example to my original question with screenshots - I am not getting the same results as you....

Comment: Ahhh. I get it now. This is a VBA bug. I'll update my answer shortly.